# New to Linux, can anyone explain these (probably simple) instructions to me?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi

As [explained here](https://tmrh20.github.io/RF24/RPi.html):

Build using SPIDEV

> 1. Make sure that spi device support is enabled and `/dev/spidev(a).(b)` is present
> 2. Install RF24, using SPIDEV
>
>    ```
>    ./configure --driver=SPIDEV
>    make; sudo make install
>    ```
> 3. See the gettingstarted example for an example of pin configuration

I’ve looked in `/dev` and there are `spidev0.1` and `0.0` in there.

I have no idea what number 2 means though. Full instructions [here](http://tmrh20.github.io/RF24/RPi.html)

I am trying to communicate with a NRF24 radio module via SPI using TMRH20's NRF24 library.

Answer (score 3):

That's definitely a shorthand, and completely fair to call them on it (I'd suggest submitting a bug report for the documentation).

What they mean is:

1. Download the RF24 source.  The URL is probably a good place to start for finding it.  I suggest "Main Page" (upper left-hand corner), then "Download" or "Source code" under useful references.
2. Unpack the source code.  Usually you would use `tar -xvzf [tar file filename]` or `unzip [zip file filename]`, but you might just use the `git` tool to grab it directly and not need to unpack if that’s something you're comfy with.
3. Change directory to the directory created when the source code was unpacked.
4. Then run the commands listed:

   - Configure sets up the build for your environment / computer system,
   - Make runs all of the compliation, and
   - Make install puts all of the compiled files into the correct places for your system.

Comment: Brilliant thank you! Everything you explained worked perfectly.

Comment: Great explanation. But the “shorthand” here is basically these three steps: `./configure` then `make` then `sudo make install`. Pretty much all source code like this runs thorough those three steps. And the `--driver=SPIDEV` is the only specific thing here where you are passing along the `driver` to the configuration part of the build.

Comment: Agreed that configure + make + make install is v. common.  However, the instructions never mentioned you needed to download the code, and for a new user, that isn't obvious, nor is it obvious what to do once it is downloaded.  The shorthand was the link to the source code (and not even a direct link), and it was rightly confusing to this person with less experience.